# How can I restore my Unity?

Tags: unity

I can't restore my Unity using reset

```
root@vitor:~# unity --reset
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
unity-panel-service: nenhum processo localizado
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2e000b8

Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:2174): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:25 unity.favorites FavoriteStoreGSettings.cpp:139 Unable to load GDesktopAppInfo for 'ubiquity-gtkui.desktop'
ERROR 2013-10-01 23:14:26 unity.launcher.trashlaunchericon TrashLauncherIcon.cpp:62 Could not create file monitor for trash uri: Operação sem suporte
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xe000a7!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-impress.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000

WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.application" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000

WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch icon: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch name: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch boolean: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch boolean: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch boolean: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000

WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Unable to fetch children: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000

WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.application" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.application" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.application" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/application0x1fbe000
WARN  2013-10-01 23:14:28 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch type: Nenhuma interface "org.ayatana.bamf.window" no objeto no caminho /org/ayatana/bamf/window48234680
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
WARN  2013-10-01 23:15:28 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:283 Calling method "InfoRequest" on object path: "/net/launchpad/lens/video" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `com.canonical.Unity.Lens' on object at path /net/launchpad/lens/video
WARN  2013-10-01 23:15:28 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:283 Calling method "SetViewType" on object path: "/net/launchpad/lens/video" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `com.canonical.Unity.Lens' on object at path /net/launchpad/lens/video

(firefox:2380): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_set_with_data: assertion `targets != NULL' failed

(firefox:2380): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_set_with_data: assertion `targets != NULL' failed
```

I use Ubuntu 12 for 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to download something like xfce and login as that (pretty easy to do from ubuntu's login screen, just click the little circle to the right of your name) and then run that command from in there. Another suggestion is to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and run that from a terminal when no one is logged into unity. Might work, might not.